# LARAVEL_START inconsistent with multiple queue workers

Tags: laravel, queue, microtime

In my Laravel app, I want to add the job execution time to each job's log. To do this I am subtracting `LARAVEL_START` from the current `microtime()` like this:

```
$data['meta']['requestDuration'] = round((microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START) * 1000, 2);
```

While working on it, I only ran one queue worker with `php artisan queue:listen`, which gave me the expected result of about 450ms.

Running the same code in production with, for example, five queue workers results in times stored, such as 19517ms. I also noticed that depending on how long the workers run, the time is increased as well.

Comment: The queue worker starts once and processes many jobs. Use another way to find the runtime.

Comment: @apokryfos but why is `php artisan queue:listen` working then?

Comment: What is `LARAVEL_START`? What does it contain?

Comment: @brombeer It's a constant defined by Laravel itself at boot containg `microtime()`.

Comment: `queue:listen` is different to `queue:work` in that `queue:listen` is used mainly for local testing and restarts after each task is processed. Differences are touched on [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Comment: @apokryfos Since I moved the "execution start" into the job itself now,  you should make your first comment an answer as it basically reflects what I did.

Comment: @StanleyRichter my comment suggested you seek another way to do it. You are the one who actually did that so I think you should share the code you used. I think my comment is a bit too broad to make it an answer